# Literal argument warning when adding item to list

Tags: android, kotlin, data-class

> `Boolean literal argument without parameter name`

Why does this warning appear when the parameter name is shown to the left of the `Boolean` value? I know how to fix this, but does the warning have to be fixed or can I just leave it as it is? The `Boolean` value will regularly change in future hence I prefer easy-to-adjust code.

**data class for item**

```
data class Food (val foodName: String,
                     val hasDairy: Boolean,
                     val hasGluten: Boolean,
                     val hasSoya: Boolean,
                     val hasWheat: Boolean)
```

**fragment class**

```
...
myList.add(Food(getString(R.string.name_of_food),
                    true,
                    false,
                    true,
                    false))
...
```

Comment: "but does the warning have to be fixed" -- if you mean "can I make my editor shut up", that will depend on your IDE or editor. If you mean "can I do something to my code to fix this", use named parameters. "The Boolean value will regularly change in future hence I prefer easy-to-adjust code" -- IMHO, and in the humble opinion of the editor developers, using named parameters is easier to adjust than is a list of undifferentiated booleans. It makes it a bit less likely that you will flip the wrong boolean, by mis-remembering which one is the gluten one.

Comment: A related approach would be to put default values on those `Boolean` values (e.g., `val hasDairy: Boolean = false`). Then, use named parameters only for those that you need to flip to `true`, and skip the other ones.

Answer (score 8):

Just change your list adding element to:

```
myList.add(Food(getString(R.string.name_of_food),
                hasDairy = true,
                hasGluten = false,
                hasSoya = true,
                hasWheat = false))
```

That will give names to your parameters and will remove the warning.